# How to register an attendee for a webinar via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, webinar

I want to register attendee in Microsoft Team Webinar by using my system, for this I need an API.

Does Graph API support to add an attendee for a webinar?

Answer (score 0):

Using following graph API you can set the **allowedRegistrant** as everyone or organization.

1.**Create meetingRegistration** - POST /me/onlineMeetings/{id}/registration

2.**Update meetingRegistration** - PATCH /me/onlineMeetings/{id}/registration

These APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Ref Doc:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingregistration-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingregistration-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http